# Sonar not scanning the parent project files

Tags: sonarqube

I have a multimodule maven project with below structure

```
   test-project(parent)-> packaging is pom       
      -  test-project.ear         
      -  test-project.war
```

The problem is I am generating a xml file during the mvn deploy phase before the sonar scan and it is generating a xml file under the parent project ,in this case it is generating immediately under the test-project.  I want this file to be scanned by Sonar, but sonar seems to scan only the xml files under the ear and war files. Could any one help me on this

I am using SonarQube 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube cannot analyse files that are in aggregator projects (i.e. projects with POM packaging).